# How to add subitem in Listview

Tags: android, listview

i have a working `ListView` I'm trying to add subitems in it. but there's seems to be a problem on `list.setAdapter(new SimpleAdapter(this, list, label, wala));`

```js
                String[] resName = new String[(int) dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount()];
                String[] resLoc;
                ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listViewRest);
                restauList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
                resLoc = new String[]{"TRY", "TRY2"};

                int i = 0;
                for (DataSnapshot dataSnapshot1 : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    resName[i] = dataSnapshot1.child("resname").getValue().toString();
                    HashMap<String, String> listahan = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    listahan.put("Restaurant Name", String.valueOf(resName));
                    listahan.put("Location", String.valueOf(resLoc));
                    restauList.add(listahan);
                    i++;
                }
                String [] label = new String[] {"Name", "Location"};
                int [] wala = new int []{ android.R.id.text1, android.R.id.text2 };

                int layout = android.R.layout.two_line_list_item;
                list.setAdapter(new SimpleAdapter(this, list, label, wala));
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use from ExpandableListView for add subItem in listView.